# Convert a double to a decimal and cap it if needed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double and need to convert it to a decimal. If the value is too large/small the result should be decimal.MaxValue/decimal.MinValue. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? When you say "best", what do you optimize for? Readability? Performance? "Correctness"? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you realize this is a lossy conversion, and should be avoided if possible? If you really need it:

```
private static readonly double MaxDecimalAsDouble = (double) decimal.MaxValue;
private static readonly double MinDecimalAsDouble = (double) decimal.MinValue;

...
public decimal ConvertWithCap(double input)
{
    return input >= MaxDecimalAsDouble ? decimal.MaxValue
         : input <= MinDecimalAsDouble ? decimal.MinValue
         : (decimal) input;
}
```

This way the cap is checked in terms of the `double` value, but then return the capped value hard-coded to be the decimal value. This avoids the problem where `double` can't accurately represent the max/min values of `decimal`.

(Even at the largest scales of `decimal`, consecutive integers can be represented - but that's not the case for `double`.)

Comment: Sadly the API I use requires this. I also came up with your solution but dismissed it. My problem is that resulting decimal, in case of an overflow, isn't decimal.MaxValue.

Comment: I thought decimal was larger than double, and so casting of decimal.MaxValue as double should have returned double.MaxValue similarly for decimal.MinValue and double.MinValue

Comment: @SuryaPratap: No, because the differences in representation mean that `decimal.MaxValue` isn't exactly representable as a `double`.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right, my bad ;) I was just checking through the references as I was not aware of this

Answer (score 0):

What would you consider as large and small values for the double??
 I feel a simple if else statement will do the job

```
public decimal getDecimal(double value,double large,double small)
{

    if(value <= large && value >= small)
     return (decimal) value;
    else if (value>large)
     return decimal.MaxValue;
    else
     return decimal.MinValue;
}
```

This is just typed into the site, so please forgive syntax and spelling

Comment: I don't know if I wasn't clear enough: the large and small boundaries _are_ decimal.MaxValue and decimal.MinValue.

Comment: @user232986 I understand now, I was not aware of the exception thrown when casting double as decimal